# Convex functions

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

How does one show that $\phi(x)$ convex and twice differentiable implies that  $x\phi(\frac{y}{x})$ is convex on the plane $x>0$? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try differentiating twice?

Comment: Writing phi as a supremum of affine functions yields a simple proof which explains why the restriction to x>0 is needed (and why the hypothesis that phi is twice differentiable is not).

Comment: Thanks guys, I have managed to solve it now :)

Comment: Could you add your proof?

Answer (score 1):

The constant $y$ is simply scaling, so it can be replaced by $1$ without losing generality.  If $\phi$ is twice differentiable, one can compute 
$$ \begin{split}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2} x\phi(x^{-1})& =\frac{d}{dx}(\phi(x^{-1})-x^{-1}\phi'(x^{-1})) \\
&=-x^{-2}\phi'(x^{-1})+x^{-2}\phi'(x^{-1} )+x^{-3}\phi''(x^{-1}) \\ 
& =x^{-3}\phi''(x^{-1}) 
\end{split}
\tag1$$
... however this is not very enlightening, since the cancellation comes as a miracle. The approach suggested by Did is better: since $\phi$ is the envelope of some family of affine functions $x\mapsto ax+b$, the transform $x\mapsto x\phi(x^{-1})$  is the envelope of some family of  functions of the form $$x\mapsto x(ax^{-1}+b)=a+bx$$